# Expected distance/ time for a bouncing ball to stop.

Tags: probability, statistics, expected-value

I saw someone on YouTube glue half of a bouncy ball to a golf ball. I thought of an interesting expected value problem using it.

Consider when you drop the ball it lands on the bouncy or non bouncy side with equal probability. When it lands on the bouncy side it returns to  $a\%$ of its height before the bounce and if it lands on the golf side it bounces and returns to $b\%$ of its height before the bounce. With $0<b<a<100$
Lets say the ball stops bouncing when it first bounces up less than $m$ centimetres.

For example, let $a = 50$, $b=10$ and $m=1$ you drop the ball from $1$ metre and it lands on the bouncy side so returns to $50$ cm. It then bounces on the golf side so returns to $5$ cm. It then bounces on the bouncy side three times so goes $2.5$, $1.25$, $0.625$ and stops bouncing.

I had a few problems that I am sure are very related.

1. If you drop the ball from $1$ metre what is the expected number of bounces?
2. If you drop the ball from $1$ metre what is the expected distance it travels before it stops bouncing.

I am happy to consider only the second question and allow for infinite bouncing, I feel like the condition on stopping bouncing will make calculations very hard.

Can we relate these two problems nicely?

**My ideas:**

1. Let $H$ denote the height of the ball after $n$ bounces. (Starting from $1$ metre)
   $H = a^X \cdot b^{n-X}$ Where $X\sim$ Bin($n,\frac{1}{2}$) denotes the number of "bouncy bounces"
2. We could probably uses logarithms to find out all different combinations that yield $H< m$ and binomial co-efficents then manually calculate EV
3. We could say on average each bounce reduces our ball's height by $\frac{b+a}{2}$ and then think use logs to work out how many bounces it would take reducing at the rate of $\frac{b+a}{2}$ to stop. But I don't think this will give a very accurate answer because of the RV.s in the exponent.
4. We can just run some code.

Please no full solutions I want to tackle this myself! Just hints for now